# autossh in background does not work anymore

Tags: ssh, macos

Prior to my updating to macOS Sierra, `autossh` worked just fine. Now, when I run it the ssh session alway terminated immediately. This is the command that I use:

```
autossh -f -M 8880 -N -y -L 8889:localhost:8888 my-server
```

When I look at the log-file, I get the following output:

```
2016/09/29 10:54:17 autossh[15328]: checking for grace period, tries = 0
2016/09/29 10:54:17 autossh[15328]: starting ssh (count 1)
2016/09/29 10:54:17 autossh[15328]: ssh child pid is 15329
2016/09/29 10:54:17 autossh[15328]: check on child 15329
2016/09/29 10:54:17 autossh[15328]: set alarm for 600 secs
2016/09/29 10:54:17 autossh[15329]: execing /usr/bin/ssh
2016/09/29 10:54:21 autossh[15328]: check on child 15329
2016/09/29 10:54:21 autossh[15328]: ssh exited with error status 255; restarting ssh
```

This goes on and on. However, when I run the same command without the `-f` option (not running in the background), everything works fine. This looks like the problem described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/534229/autossh-in-background-does-not-work), but I'm not using a custom id.

What could be the cause for this, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since macOS Sierra, `ssh-add` doesn't automatically load keys added with `ssh-add -K` on startup. In order for this to work, I had to add `ssh-add -A` to my `.bashrc`, now things work as expected.